# How does the proof of Fermat's little theorem work which uses inverses?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am struggling to understand the proof of Fermat's little Theorem which uses inverses.

Namely,consider the set of numbers $S=\{1,2,3,\cdots,p-1 \}$ and consider the set $a\cdot S=\{a,2a,\cdots,a(p-1)\}$ ,then if we can prove that $a \cdot S$ is distinct ,then the proof is concluded as this implies that $a\cdot S$ is a permutation of $S$.

Here I don't understand how the fact that $a\cdot S$ is distinct implies that it is a permutation of $S$ .

I've just started studying this ,so please explain it at a basic level...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick any two distinct elements in $aS$, say $as_1$ and $as_2$.

$as_1 \equiv as_2 \pmod p \iff s_1 \equiv s_2 \pmod p$

beacuse we assume $a$ is invertible.

So the set $aS$ is composed by $p-1$ distinct elements in $\mathbb Z_p^*$.

But $|\mathbb Z_p^*|=p-1$

so they are just the elements of $\mathbb Z_p^*$ written in a different oreder.

Comment: I get the manipulation you've done but conceptually can you tell me how does the fact that $ as_1 \equiv as_2 \implies s_1 \equiv s_2 $ implies that $a \cdot S$ is distinct ?What's the underlying logic ?

Comment: Your set $S$ is composed by $p-1$ elements created multiplying $a$ with all the $p-1$ different invertible elements $s_i$: $as_1,as_2 \cdots$. Are two of them the same element? If two are the same, let's say $as_i \equiv as_j$ then $s_i \equiv s_j$, but we said that we created $S$ multiplying $a$ with all the distinct invertible elements $s_i$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.One last question :you write that $a \cdot S$ is composed by the $p-1$ different invertible elements,but I don't see why this is the case,only the first $\cfrac{p-1}{2}$ elements are different,the others are duplicates .What am I mistaking ?

Comment: $S$ is composed by $1,2,3, \cdots, p-1$ which are all different numbers.. $aS$ is composed by $1a,2a,3a \cdots (p-1)a$ which are $p-1$. But are they all different? Yes, cause if $2a \equiv 3a$ you can simplify $a$ and get $2 \equiv 3$, that is absurd. Thus $aS$ is composed by $p-1$ different elements.

Answer (score 1):

We know that, given $a\in S$, that $a$ has an inverse $\mod p$. Now if $ax\equiv ay\mod p$, we can multiply both sides by the inverse so that $x\equiv y\mod p$. This means that the elements off $a\cdot S$ are distinct.

We now know that $a\cdot S$ has $p-1$ distinct elements, all nonzero, so those elements *must* be $\{1,2,\cdots,p-1\}$, but perhaps in a different order.

But I also want to mention that in the proof for Fermat's Little Theorem, the order of those elements is irrelevant.

I hope this helped!

Comment: How do we know that in the new set $a \cdot S$ we have $ax \equiv ay \mod p $ ?

Comment: @Mr.Y , we use that argument to show that all elements are distinct - we assume two are the same, and conclude that the originals must be the same. If the originals therefore are different, then so are $ax$ and $ay$

Comment: When you say that the elements of $\cdots a S$ must be the elements of $S$ are you saying that they're the same or that they're conguent ?

Comment: They're congruent, which is in this context also referred to as "the same"

Answer (score 1):

What the author is trying to say:

If each element in $a\cdot S=\{a,2a,3a,\ldots,a(p-1)\}$ is distinct, then we know that the function $\Bbb{Z}_p\to\Bbb{Z}_p$ given by $s\mapsto as$ is a *permutation*.

Recall that a permutation is just a bijection from one set to itself.

To see that this is a permutation, we just have to see that the function is a bijection.

Injective: suppose $as_1=as_2$. Since every element in $a\cdot S$ is distinct, clearly $s_1=s_2$.

Surjective: pick any element in $\Bbb{Z_p}$. Since each element in $a\cdot S$ is distinct, and there are $p-1$ elements in the set, we must have each possible number in the set, so there has to be a pre-image of our number.

Comment: Forgive me if I am mistaking,but shouldn't we have $s_1 \ne s_2 $ ?

Comment: @Mr.Y to prove injectivity in general we want to show $f(x)=f(y)\implies x=y$

Comment: But are you writing that $s_1=s_2$ to show that it leads to a contradiction as the elements of $S$ are distinct or are we actually saying they 're equal?

Comment: yes they're equal. intuitively, this is says that the only way for two elements to map to the same thing is if they are actually the same element.